# Using JavaScript async instead of setInterval

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

Let's say I want to run the function `update()` every second.

I can do that in two ways:

```
async function interval() {
  await new Promise((res, req) => { 
    setTimeout(res, 1000)
  })
  update()
  interval()
}
```

or

```
setInterval(update, 1000)
```

Is there any functional difference between the two?

Comment: You can catch interval if you use a promise: `interval().catch(err=>...)`

Comment: You can cancel `setInterval` but cant cancel the `Promise` implementation

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that your `interval` functions returns a promise for when it is finished. You will need to add a `return` though so that it works properly:

```
async function interval() {
  await new Promise((res, req) => { 
    setTimeout(res, 1000)
  })
  update()
  return interval()
//^^^^^^
}
```

Now when `update` throws an exception, the promise is rejected and you can `.catch()` the error. Also the `interval` recursive calls would stop running, in contrast to the `setInterval` which would just continue.

Also `async`/`await` syntax has the advantage that you can avoid recursion to create loops:

```
async function interval() {
  while (true) {
    await new Promise((res, req) => { 
      setTimeout(res, 1000)
    })
    update()
  }
}
```

Comment: when update throws an exception, promise will not be rejected!, promise has no connection with update function

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain Of course it does! The promise returned by `interval()` is rejected when any of the code inside the body throws an exception. Including the `update()` call.

Comment: why do you think interval() is returning promise?

Comment: @AkshayVijayJain Uh, because it's an `async function`? That's how async/await works.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is asking difference between settimeout and setinterval to achieve repetition, I feel here there is no relevance of asycn/await, you have just used it to avoid calling same function in setTimeout. 
Or you might say the relevance is async/await is doing, what setTimeout does, however as pointed by Ayush, you do not have any option to cancel the loop, which you get with setTimeout
 
So following link might answer your curiosity.
[setTimeout or setInterval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729921/settimeout-or-setinterval)

Thanks